# Is there a time field where I can fill in the time I want?

Tags: biblatex, datetime

I am going to add a web page to the bibliography, and therefore I need to add the time. I did not add the web page in latex when I got it from the web, so I need to add the time I actually used the web page to find information.

At the moment I have this:

```
@website{website-name,
author    = {author},
title     = {title},
url       = {url.com},
urldate = {2015-03-10},
}
```

Is there a time field so I can add the time I want, and not use \currenttime?

Comment: Normally `urldate` is for the access date. Do you use a bibliography manager that changes `urldate` automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you mean time or date? Normally the date is sufficient!

Comment: Can you get a bit more specific in your question? Did you actually mean to add the time (and not only the date) of access?